# Python regular expressions (extracting monetary value from a string)

Tags: python, regex

I am munging data which contains strings of the form:

```
" The little £250,000 brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
```

**[Clarification]**

The string to be converted to a double may have been "cleaned" already and may simply look like this:

```
"£250,000"
```

I managed to hack together a crude function, that bludgeons a string like "£250,000" into a double. However, I am at my wits end to write a regex to grok the monetary part of the string, when presented with a string like the one above. The problem is that I don't know which type of string I will encounter - i.e. either a 'cleaned' monetary value (like the 2nd example) or a 'dirty' string (like the first example). I need to write a single function that handles both types of strings and returns the monetary string as a double.

For 'dirty' strings, can someone recommend how to pattern match the monetary values (expected minimum: £1, expected maximum £99,999,999). Also, if there is a more pythonic way of writing the function below, I'd like to hear recommendations from the Pythonistas out there.

```
    non_numeric = re.compile(r'[^0-9\.]+')

    def string_to_decimal(s):
        try:
            s= s.decode('ascii')
        except:
            s = s[1:] # Assumption is that s begings with currency symbol

        s = str(s)  # Probably superfulous?

        s = s.replace(',','')
        s = non_numeric.sub('', str(s))
        return decimal.Decimal(s)
```

Comment: `s = str(s)` would make sense before the `try`.  Since decode only works on strings, and indexing doesn't work on integers, you can assume it's a string after the `try/except`.  Otherwise, your program will throw an exception inside the `except` (which won't be caught).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
re.findall('£{1}[,0-9]{1,10}','The little £250,000 brown fox jumped over the lazy dog')
```

Then take the result of the match and strip commas out.

Comment: +1: I used your regex expression as well in my complete solution, to match on 'dirty' strings

Answer (score 2):

```
r'£\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+(?:\.\d{2})?'
```

will match monetary expressions, e.g.

```
>>> re.findall(r'£\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+(?:\.\d{2})?',
... " The little £250,000 brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
['\xc2\xa3250,000']
```

You can convert the resulting values to `Decimal` with

```
>>> Decimal('\xc2\xa3250,000'.decode('utf-8')[1:].strip(','))
Decimal('250000')
```

(Assuming UTF-8.)

Comment: I'm getting the following error (when using the snippet above): SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /path/to/myscript.py on line 140, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details. I'll check  the URL for details

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file. That tells the Python interpreter about the source file's encoding.

Comment: Thanks that fixed that error. However, I need to clarify, i need to be able to match on strings like '£250,000' as well (where there is no other text surrounding the monetray value).

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: so? `re.match(r'£\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+(?:\.\d{2})?', "£250,000")` works, doesn't it?

Comment: I expected it to match - but it didn't. I must be doing something wrong at my end. I'll check and try again.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: probably some encoding issue. Try `re.match(ur'£\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+(?:\.\d{2})?', u"£250,000")` (note the Unicode strings).

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: that's because you're using `re.match`. Use `re.search` or `re.findall` to search within a string.

Answer (score 0):

If the input text can be in various languages, you need to be afraid of the difference in punctuation for different locales.

What you call "£250,000" would be "£250.000" in some locales, and the inverse goes for fractions: "£0.50" can be written as "£0,50". There are probably more varieties.

Ignoring that, your example should be handled by a regular expression such as `r"£[0-9,.]+"`, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with installing an additional python package named [`price-parser`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/price-parser), then you can try the following:

Install the package

```
python -m pip install price-parser
```

Code to get the currency and amount

```py
from price_parser import Price
result = Price.fromstring(" The little £250,000 brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Price(amount=Decimal('250000'), currency='£')
```